# My tableview is setting the data before the cell is being registered

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableview cell in my story i'm trying to register it with my custom tableview. inside the tableview cellforrow function i'm manipulating my cell labels and it's giving me nil. I believe since the cell is not registered yet. does the cellforrow loads before the viewdidload method? my code is as following.

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AllTasksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    let tableView = UITableView()
  
     override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController()
        tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"taskCell")

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        
        tableView.reloadData()
        print(coreTasks.count)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return coreTasks.count
    }
 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let task = coreTasks[indexPath.row]

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell") as! CustomCell 
           
       cell.setTask(task: task) // this changes the label and date text since an instance of the task contains both the task and the date

       return cell    
     }
}
```

The error that i am facing is in my custom tableview cell function "setTask".

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet var taskLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
//    @IBOutlet var iconsCell: UIImageView!



func setTask(task: NSManagedObject ){
    taskLabel.text = task.value(forKey: "name") as? String
    dateLabel.text = task.value(forKey: "date") as?
    String

}

func labelsToWhite() {
    taskLabel.textColor = .white
    dateLabel.textColor = .white
}

func labelsToBlack() {
    taskLabel.textColor = .black
    dateLabel.textColor = .red
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but why do you add the table view to the parent view twice?

Comment: it's a mistake. it's still crashing :)

Comment: What is the purpose of `storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController`?

Comment: @CharlesLenx - *"... i'm manipulating my cell labels and it's giving me nil ..."* You have not shown any code related to cell labels.... What's giving you nil?

Comment: I added the code for my custom cell where it's giving me nil

Comment: You are using IBOutlets. Those are only valid if you create your tableview from a storyboard and use prototype cells. If you create your cells just by registering a class then you will need to create the views in the cell yourself

Comment: @CharlesLenx - you're doing a number of things wrong. Why are you calling `instantiateInitialViewController`? Your `CustomCell` class appears to be a Prototyped cell in Storyboard (based on the `@IBOutlet` lines), but you're not using a tableview from Storyboard. You're calling `reloadData()` for no reason. I suggest you go through a few tutorials on how to use custom table view cells. It's too much for an answer or discussion here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -2):

So what i think is your problem is that you are setting the dataSource before setting the delegate. This means that you are creating a standard UITableView with the correct data, and then saying by the way i want it to look like this but its already set up so nothing is happening.

This is how you have done it:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    ...
}
```

What you should do is flipping this like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn’t work like that. Those parts of the code run on the main thread (line by line) and at that time, it is just setting properties. Till the end of that method, in this case viewdidload, if you don’t call any of the tableView methods directly like reloadData, nothing bad happens and it doesn’t matter in what order you set the properties.